# How should I handle a bad edit on an already (helpfully) flagged answer?

Tags: discussion, flags

Today I flagged an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34893014/1) that popped up during reviews. I flagged it as *not an answer*, because the dumped code did not solve the original question. I also left a comment to the answerer, telling him, that his answer would not solve the problem.

Shortly after, my flag deemed helpful as I can see on my profile; the post however did not get deleted. Instead, shortly after, I got a notification that the answerer commented my comment. He had edited his answer, but the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34893014/3) made the content even worse.

*Basically it is now just a link only answer that links to a question, that does not even provide a solution to a question that is now over two years old*. Pretty complicated and pretty bad in my opinion.

I would flag this answer as *not an answer* again (already left a comment as well) to have others deal with it, but it says:

> You have already raised this type of flag

Fine, I did, and the flag got handled apparently, but the answer is still bad. Now, how should I proceed? Raise a moderator flag, explaining the issue? It seems unnecessary to bother a moderator with the deletion of a simple link-only answer.

What options do I have in this case? I searched Meta, but I only found questions about disputed flags - which this is not.

---

*BTW: I am not sure about what tags fit best here, feel free to suggest better ones.*

Comment: You could write a meta question about it. ;-)

Comment: Good thinking, I might do that! :)

Comment: The edit of the OP dismissed your flag. You can always hop into the [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) if you need assistance to have a second opinion on flags that might have been dismissed after editing. You might find the [timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34893014/timeline) useful to determine if your edit might have pushed the review task out the queue

Comment: _"I flagged it as not an answer because the dumped code did not solve the original question"_ - that's not what that flag is for. Now they made it a link-only answer at it is at -3, so people can vote to delete it.

Comment: Wow @rene, the timeline is awesome! Where can I find it usually? I still am a little scared about the chat, but I guess, it might be worth going there next time.

Comment: Wrong answers are **not**, not an answer.  They are an answer, they are just wrong,  If you see a wrong answer you can down vote, comment about it, cast a delete vote (20K priv with restrictions).

Comment: Thanks for your input, CodeCaster and NathanOliver. I will mind this in future

Comment: @T3H40 the timeline can only be reached by handcrafting the url. And chat can be daunting, sure. In the SOCVR you'll find users with strong opinions but we are also a room with a strict set of [guidelines](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation/blob/master/README.md) which should prevent that things escalate ...

Comment: @rene, thanks! Yes, I had a little read of some posts and the guidelines a while ago, I think during election. But I sure will have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer got [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34893014/timeline). Thank you for your participation, meta saved the day again :)

Comment: Note; The status-completed tag will not be added. That tag is only for [added changes in source control.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/status-completed/info). An accepted answer will be enough